# Where is the <%=Html.RadioButtonList()%> extension in MVC beta?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods

Is there any reason why there isnt a radiobutton list helper in the core MVC beta? There's a dropdownlist, but no radiobuttonlist.

I know that I can easily create an extension method to do surely this is a core thing?

Answer (score 2):

its in the mvc futures you can dowload on codeplex. but i believe it has bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was removed for the sake of simplification, instead you can just use a foreach loop.

Comment: But how would this make it more simplified? And for whom is it more simplified for?

Comment: I just want a "yes"/"no" instead of a checkbox. There doesn't seem to be an easy way to implement this, and I'm not sure why.